# Can I change "Activities" in gnome-shell to an Ubuntu logo?

Tags: gnome, customization

I'm using gnome-shell in Oneiric and would like to know if there is a way to change the text "Activities" (in the top left corner) to a picture if the Ubuntu logo. I have already succeeded at replacing it with "Ubuntu" by editing one line in this file:

`/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js`:

From:

```
this._label = new St.Label({ text: _("Activities") });
```

To:

```
this._label = new St.Label({ text: _("Ubuntu") });
```

Anyone with js expertise here? Could I possibly change this to something like

```
this._label = new St.Label({ image: _(/use/share/icons/ubuntu.ico) });
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm looking for that also. If you check back in at this site:

[Gnome-Shell Extensions](http://www.fpmurphy.com/gnome-shell-extensions/)

You will see a note stating that he will be updating his extensions to work with 3.2 over the next few weeks.

Go into the 3.0 extensions link and you will see an link for activitiesbutton.tar.gz

That is an extension that allows you to select an icon to replace the activities label in gnome 3.0, but as yet I haven't been able to recode it successfully myself to work with 3.2, so am waiting on fpmurphy to do it ;0)

If you have any more luck with it please post back here and let me know :)

Cheers!

Comment: The extension is now available for gnome-shell 3.2. Sadly, this version interfers with the theme I'm using. Every time I turn it on, it set it back to the default theme. I have looked at the code and I still haven't figured out how to preserve the user theme.